# Unknown constraint affecting buttons in an IOS storyboard? (Making Text Look Right in Custom Button)

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard, constraints

I have a simple view with a title, a scroll view (for text), and a couple of buttons. I created the view in my storyboard. Everything is working perfectly except that there seems to be some hidden constraint affecting one of my buttons.

The button titles are set in code. Setting them makes the button get wider as expected. I have the following constraints on the buttons:

- Each of them have width >= 73
- The left button has the standard horizontal constraint between it and the left edge of its base view. The right button has the standard horizontal constraint between it and the right edge of the base view. (In other words, I lined them up with the guides - the constraints were created automatically.)
- One button has a height of 44 and a vertical constraint with the bottom of the base view.
- The other is bottom- and top-aligned with it.

That's it.

The problem I'm having is that even though there appears to be plenty of space between the two buttons (and no constraint between them), if the button text is large enough, the insets from the side edges of the button to the title become virtually zero, so that the text is shown right up against the button's edges. When I manually add an edge inset, using

```
self.okButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 0.6);
```

the text gets squashed (ellipses appear inside it). Meanwhile there is about 65 pts of space between the two buttons, which is more than plenty.

The only thing I can think of is that there is some invisible constraint preventing my button from getting any bigger. But I'm not seeing one. All I need is about 10-15 pts for everything to look good.

Thanks for any insights you can give me.

UPDATE (ANSWER): I found this very helpful [post](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html). It turns out that I needed to set `self.okbutton.contentEdgeInsets`. And call it before setting my button title (which automatically seems to call `sizeToFit:`). The problem was that I was using a custom button (that has no built-in insets), so I did need to set them myself; I just wasn't using the correct property. Using `titleEdgeInsets` with positive insets actually made the area in which the text could be drawn smaller, which is why it was squashing the text. Apparently, it is only really a useful property when you're trying to indent your text. You have to offset the indent by passing a negative inset to the corresponding other side in order to not make the text draw area smaller. Ie., `button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetMake(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0)` will move the text in your button to the right without squashing your text).

Comment: Are you sure that your width constraint of 73 is >= not = ? I tried using the constraints you say you have, and it worked fine for me (with no edge insets).

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I'm using a custom button. So there is no default inset. It turns out that the problem was that I was using titleEdgeInsets instead of contentEdgeInsets. contentEdgeInsets creates space (like I wanted). titleEdgeInsets only makes the space smaller, unless you balance your positive left inset with a negative right one, in which case it just moves your text over. I found this explanation: http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html, which really helped.